# Is there a way to automatically import issues from Jira into Taiga?

Tags: jira, agile, agile-project-management

Just started using Taiga.io, and was wondering if there was a way to auto-import issues/stories so I don't have to manually rewrite them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make some sort of sync program/script that pulls from a JIRA project into a Tangia project.

Example. Have a file that contains the latest JIRA issue key that exists within Taiga and then the script runs every hour. Upon execution it does a REST call to get any issues above that JIRA key (Ex. TEST-5):

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=key%20>%20TEST-5%20order%20by%20key%20desc
```

Then it updates the file with the highest key value and then pushes each issue into Taiga which can be done using the [Taiga REST API](http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/api.html#tasks-create).

Additionally you may be able to do something with the JIRA Workflow so that when issues are created something occurs within the workflow that calls the Taiga REST API and creates the task automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just save them in a format recognized by both Jira and Taiga than each time the file changes you just import it to Taiga (I used csv Excel and it worked pretty fine). The only downside is that you need to stay loggedin 24/7 if you work with worldwide distributed teams in order for the auto-function to work...